# C# RabbitMQ EventBasicConsumer for one message?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I want to create method:

```
bool TryPullMessage(string queue, out T message, TimeSpan? timeout = null);
```

which will try to pull **one** message from queue (I configured Qos for 1 message at a time) and will fail after timeout. For implementation I have two choises:

1. To use manual request in loop: model.BasicGet(queue, ...)
2. To use consumer: new EvenBasicConsumer(model)

However, I don't want to use first approach because it creates unlimited traffic and resource consumption. For the second approach I tried many things like this:

```
            var parent = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
            var child = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);

            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_model);
            consumer.Received += (sender, args) =>
            {
                //save message localy
                    parent.Set();
                    child.WaitOne();
            };
            _model.BasicConsume(queue, true, consumer);
            try
            {
                parent.WaitOne(timeout.Value);
            }
            finally
            {
                _model.BasicCancel(consumer.ConsumerTag);
                child.Set();
            }
```

But without success, it just keeps consuming them. Is it possible to use RabbitMQ pushes for one single message?